# Breakpoints css is not applied over props in React-jss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-in-js

I am getting an issue with React-JSS.
I have created a modal class for which the property of height depends on the prop passed to the component.
In responsive design I want the height to be `100%` but somehow it is not getting priority in CSS because React-JSS creating two classes when I used props inside styles.

React JSS Code

```
  modal: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: 750px,
    height: ({ height = 550 } => height,
    [breakpoints.MOBILE]: {
      height: 'auto',
    },
  },
```

**Output**

It creates two classes because I am accessing props in the styles and media queries not getting priority.

[image]

Looking forward for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing your styles as [docs says](https://cssinjs.org/jss-syntax?v=v10.0.0) this way:

```
modal: {
  borderRadius: 10,
  width: 750px,
  height: ({ height = 550 } => height,
},
[breakpoints.MOBILE]: {
  modal: {
    height: 'auto'
  }
}
```

Update. If you want nested properties such as media queries or additional selectors, you need to include this official plugin: https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.0.0

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. `jss-plugin-nested` already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Old post now, but I had the same issue and this is what worked for me (using your example to go off of):

```
modal: {
  borderRadius: 10,
  width: 750px,
  height: ({ height = 550 }) => height,
  [breakpoints.MOBILE]: {
    height: () => { return 'auto'; },
  },
},
```

tl;dr, it seems if you use a prop function to define a style somewhere, you must use one everywhere.  Then it will pick up the styles in your breakpoint.